# I want to record video and audio at the same time but i dont know how to?

Tags: c#, aforge, accord.net

I'm using accord.net i record audio and video separatly but I want to do both at the same time because i will read the video with sound while its recorded in another app using sockets.

I read somewhere to use videofilewriter but i dont know how to use it with audio.
i'm running the recording in background because it make the form freeze.

```
  public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
 // back ground running
        bg = new BackgroundWorker();
        bg.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        bg.DoWork += Run;
        audiostream = new MemoryStream();
        audioencoder = new WaveEncoder(audiostream);            
    }    
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        VideoCaptureDevices = new 
        FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
        captureDevice = new VideoCaptureDeviceForm();
    }

 private void source_NewFrame(object sender, Accord.Audio.NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        audioencoder.Encode(eventArgs.Signal);
    }

    void FinalVideo_NewFrame(object sender, Accord.Video.NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        video = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
        pictureBox1.Image = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone(); ;
    }

 private void record_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        source = new AudioCaptureDevice()
        {
            // Listen on 44.1 Hz, Cam Quality 1280x720
            DesiredFrameSize = 4096,
            SampleRate = 44100,
        };

 saveFileDialog2.Filter = "Wav Files (*.wav)|*.wav";
 saveFileDialog2.InitialDirectory = @"C:\Users\dell\Desktop\Camrecord";
 saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Avi Files (*.avi)|*.avi";
 saveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = @"C:\Users\dell\Desktop\Camrecord";

 int h = captureDevice.VideoDevice.VideoResolution.FrameSize.Height;
 int w = captureDevice.VideoDevice.VideoResolution.FrameSize.Width;
 audiofilestream = new FileStream(saveFileDialog2.FileName, 
FileMode.Create);
 FileWriter.Open(saveFileDialog1.FileName, w, h, 155, VideoCodec.MPEG4, 
3200000);
source.NewFrame += source_NewFrame;
source.Start();
bg.RunWorkerAsync();

}

 private void Run(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        audioencoder = new WaveEncoder(audiofilestream);

        do
        {
            Runexecuted = true;               
            FileWriter.WriteVideoFrame(video);

       } while (!Stopclicked);

        FinalVideo = captureDevice.VideoDevice;
        FinalVideo.NewFrame += new 
        NewFrameEventHandler(FinalVideo_NewFrame);
        source.NewFrame += source_NewFrame;
        source.Start();
        FinalVideo.Start();
    }
```

if you know how to merge them i can use it, pending the solution that would suit me. thanks to all of you.

Answer (score 0):

You had to set the save event at the end of the recording, not at the start.